# C code - malloc and free

Tags: c, memory-management, overflow

consider the below code:

```
int main()

{

int *a,address,size;

    a= (int *) malloc(10);
    address=(int*) a-1;
    size=(int ) *(a-1); // sorry there was a bug wrong casting, now its corrected.
    printf("address of malloc n:%d\n",address);
    printf("size of malloc block b:%d\n",size);
    printf("before%p",a);
    a=a+1;
    printf("\n after%p",a);    
    free(a);

    getch();

}
```

Address of the malloc "a" was incremented and then freed (a+1). It will lead to memory leak, but how will the free know the end point till it has to free so that it will not free the next chunk of memory by mistake? Is there any end marker like in Char Array - '\0'?

I read in K&R chapter 8 section 8.7 that free maintains a list from which the free will know were to add back the free memory block to.

Is there any size from which table its declared by malloc? Then how will the above code work, i guess this is were the free list comes to picture right?  Its just going to add the free linked list  i.e a+1 on words only. and forget about the other memory location which will lead to memory leak.

But when you do a malloc(), I read that it returns a pointer-1 and will give the Size of the malloc block that was allocated, am I right?

Can anyone explain this in detail?

Question is not related to Code. **its how exactly the Malloc and free function work with each other. if i say free(a), how exactly will the free function know the end of the block?**

Comment: There's nothing to explain. The code causes *undefined behaviour* on several occasions and anything could happen.

Answer (score 3):

All that can be said the `free(a+1)` call is that it leads to undefined behaviour, since `a+1` has never been returned by `malloc()` et al.

Upon closer inspection, the `size=(int *)*(a-1)` line also leads to undefined behaviour, since you're dereferencing a pointer outside the allocated region.

The mechanics of memory allocation (i.e. things like free lists) are implementation-specific and should not be relied upon except in *very* specific and *very* rare circumstances.

**edit** If you curious to learn how a possible implementation *might* work, here is a description of one popular `malloc()` implementation: [`dlmalloc`](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html).

Comment: thanks for ur comment. but my Question is not related to Code. its how exactly the Malloc and free function work with each other.

if i say free(a), how exactly will the free function know the end of the block?

Comment: @PKS - we don't know. Someone will have to keep track of the allocations somehow, but the language standard doesn't say how to do that. Or who has to do it. Perhaps the OS does it for you? Perhaps not.

Comment: yes, as far as i have understood, its the OS. looks like its OS depended. Thanks

Comment: @PKS: I've added a link to a page describing `dlmalloc`, a popular implementation of `malloc`.

Answer (score 3):

You are in the realm of **undefined behavior**.

Free must be passed a pointer returned by malloc as per the standard:

> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be
>   deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation.  If ptr
>   is a null pointer, no action occurs.  Otherwise, **if the argument does
>   not match a pointer earlier returned by the calloc , malloc , or
>   realloc function**, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to
>   free or realloc , **the behavior is undefined**.

-- ANSI Standard 1988

Section 4.10.3.2 :The free function

Comment: thanks for ur comment. but my Question is not related to Code. its how exactly the Malloc and free function work with each other. if i say free(a), how exactly will the free function know the end of the block? –

Comment: @PKS: The implementation of `malloc` is, obviously, implementation-defined.

Comment: @PKS That is the implementation's job. The implementation usually has to store some sort of additional data along with the allocation.

Comment: @Ethan, just wanted to learn more.. does that mean that Malloc in one compiler behaves different compared to other. then how can i understand the implementation of malloc/free on each system that im working on?

Comment: @PKS Read the source code of your libc. [Here](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/) is gcc's version. Look in [releases](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/) and download it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't ask the sorts of questions you have about C implementations in general. You are making assumptions about the C implementation, some of which may be true, but they aren't guaranteed to be true by the C standard. Perhaps on some implementations, freeing an invalid pointer means you have a memory leak, and perhaps on some implementations, reading the 4 bytes prior to the pointer returned by `malloc` will give you the size of the allocated memory, but this is not standardised. The code you have written invokes undefined and implementation-defined behaviour in a number of places. Without knowing what C implementation you are talking about, it is impossible to tell you what the code will do. When a program invokes undefined behaviour, the implementation is free to do whatever it wants to do. A conforming C implementation can cause your computer to melt down into a steaming pile of silicon for freeing an invalid pointer. Will it? Don't know. The behaviour of your code is undefined.

How `free` and `malloc` are implemented depend on the implementation, not on the C standard. The C standard explains what the functions do and it is up to each individual C implementation to provide conforming versions of `free` and `malloc` based on the descriptions of these functions in the C standard.